# Getting the hidden input value from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am unable to get the value of hidden input from ajax to PHP with the following code. Here the problem is I don't know the id of input. I mean its dynamic.

```
<div id="comboproducts">
 foreach ($comboproducts as $product) {
<input type="hidden" id="comboproductsid<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" /> 
}
</div>
```

ajax part

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/addcombo',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#comboproducts input[type=\'hidden\']'),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#button-cart').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#button-cart').button('reset');
    },
    success: function(json) {

   alert(json);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This should be `$('#comboproducts input[type=\'hidden\']')` -> `$('#comboproducts input[type=\'hidden\']').val()` .

Comment: But how will i achieve this in PHP as id will be change everytime... if id Is not dynamic its easy to get it in PHP. but now id will different everytime so its quite difficult to get it in php

Comment: How you call your ajax? onclick of something ? can you show your html generated code ?

Comment: onclick! everything is perfect... instead i am unable to achieve the dynamic input values in PHP code

Comment: Place a name in you input and use $_POST in php to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to the `data` you are sending in your AJAX payload. It appears you are using both POST and GET in your script. The post data should be an Object.

Now if there are multiple IDs of the same type of element, you will need to capture this in your `click` callback before you call the AJAX. If there is only one, you can use an attribute selector like `$("[id^='comboproductsid']")` See More: [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/addcombo',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    "product_id": $("input[type='hidden'][id^='comboproductsid']").val()
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#button-cart').button('loading');
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('#button-cart').button('reset');
  },
  success: function(json) {
    alert(json);
  }
});
```

In your PHP, this can be reached from `$_POST['product_id']`.

Answer (score 0):

If I have keys that define the values, I simply add a name attribute to the hidden text field and place the key value as the name. Then iterate over the post values and if those are set, I get those values.

EX array

```
$comboproducts = array(
    'tv' => array(
        'product_id' => 23,
        'price' => 34.23,
        'stock' => 31,
        'shipable' => true
    ),
    'phone' => array(
        'product_id' => 3,
        'price' => 250.99,
        'stock' => 99,
        'shipable' => true
    )

);
$stmt = null;
foreach ($comboproducts as $key => $product) {
    $stmt .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$product['product_id'].'">';
}
$value=null;
foreach ($comboproducts as $key => $product) {
    if(isset($_POST[$key])){
        $value[$key] = $_POST[$key];
    } 
}

print_r($value);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( 
  [tv] => 23 
  [phone] => 3 
)
```